# Is there a way to localize app name with xcconfig files?

Tags: xcode, localization, localizable.strings

I have come across the other threads and was unable to find a solution specific to my situation.

I have three config files (DEV, QA, Prod)

In each of the xcconfig files, I override the $(product_name)
ex: PRODUCT_NAME = MyNameDev

This works great but now I need to localize the app in two languages and in 3 different environments.

In english:

```
Prod -> MyName
DEV -> MyNameDev
QA -> MyNameQA
```

In French:

```
Prod -> MyFrenchName
DEV -> MyFrenchNamepDev
QA -> MyFrenchNameQA
```

Comment: Hi! did you find solution?

Comment: Hey did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @dilaver no I haven't. We ended up removing the localization from the app name as we prioritized tagging the dev environments.

Answer (score -2):

Update : Not working anymore, i'll try to find a new solution

Old answer :
*Your **Info.plist** has a special file **(InfoPlist.strings)** in which you can put string overrides for other languages. To give the app a different name in French, open Supporting Files > InfoPlist.strings (French) and insert the following:
"CFBundleDisplayName" = PRODUCT_NAME;
Hope this helps :)*

Comment: Thats not what I'm asking though